# Joysticks and gamepads in Wine

Tags: wine, xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 controller with the wireless-USB pickup and I'm using the `xboxdrv` driver. The result is a joypad that all my native games (that know about joysticks, eg Super Meat Boy, Shank, Jamestown, X², Steel Storm, etc) can use. It's awesome and would thoroughly recommend it.

My problem is I have a few non-native games I play through Wine. They seem to have no idea that the controller is there. I'd guess that Wine either doesn't support it or just doesn't do it automatically.

So is there a way? I'd ideally like instructions specifically for the Xbox controller if there's any mapping required.

Comment: Also see my more recent answer to [How do I get an XBOX 360 controller working?](http://askubuntu.com/a/399662/) to get it working without xboxdrv in newer versions of Ubuntu/Wine.

Answer (score 3):

At this moment there is only few support for USB. If there will be more in future, isn't clear yet. See [USB device support in Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/USB).

If there will be more hardware support in general is also clear: No. 
wine is a compatibility layer on the linux kernels layer. See [Can I use Wine to install drivers for my hardware?](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8021e00ae87d4fbfb607739af82bdb621b9d9366)

Answer (score 0):

Try Antimicro application, just top and working with wine!

http://www.ryochan7.com/projects/antimicro/

[image]