# Xbox 360 Controller through PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I am running Skyrim through PlayOnLinux and I want to get my Xbox 360 controller to work on the game. I am using Wine 1.7.11, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and whatever version of PlayOnLinux is available through USC.

Comment: See my answer there for a great solution without the need of xboxdrv: http://askubuntu.com/a/399662/3940

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PlayOnLinux before, but I've used an xbox 360 controller as a mouse using [xboxdrv](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/).  I'm guessing this will make it work but you might have to mess around with some settings on PlayOnLinux first, but this will definitely make the controller work with ubuntu.

To install xboxdrv, I used these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends jstest* joystick xboxdrv
sudo rmmod xpad
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
```

then to run just type (when I first started using this I had to use "sudo rmmod xpad" before it would work each time):

```
xboxdrv --silent
```

To calibrate and configure the controller, run:

```
jstest-gtk
```

clicking on properties with the device selected will enable you to calibrate it.

Finally I'll leave you with a [link](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/xboxdrv.html) to all the various things you can do with xboxdrv and how to do them.  There's loads of stuff here to read through, but you can do some pretty cool stuff with it if you've got time to figure it all out!

This is what worked for me.  [Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working) where I got most of my information.  If anything doesn't work I'd refer to that page and see if any of the solutions there help.

I hope my ramblings have been useful in some way! :D

Comment: I could not get this to work, when I would type xboxdrv --silent I would get back an error saying "no xbox or xbox controller found", I dont know if this is due to the fact that I am using an aftermarket Power A controller or what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, I think this may be specific to official xbox controllers.  You might want to try some of the other solutions listed in the last link I gave above.

Comment: You also can't use a wireless one and tether it