# How to get my xbox 360 joypad to work in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I have a third party wired xbox 360 joypad that I am trying to us for emulators. How do I get this thing to work?

Comment: Isn't the controller detected by default? For Wine see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and configuring xboxdrv (xbox driver)

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv && sudo xboxdrv
```