# Fix XPad Driver

Tags: 14.04

I followed the first answer here: [How do I get an XBOX 360 controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working), and ended up screwing with my XPad drivers. How can I reverse all of the commands and restore my XPad Driver?

I used these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends jstest* joystick xboxdrv
echo "blacklist xpad" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo rmmod xpad  # unload module if already loaded
xboxdrv --silent
jstest-gtk
```

Then I edited `/etc/init/xboxdrv.conf` and added

```
start on filesystem
exec xboxdrv -D
expect fork
```

Comment: Install the driver by : `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-elographics`

Answer (score 0):

I would first run the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and edit the displayed file to remove the line:

```
blacklist xpad
```

Exit the file with CTRL+X and press Y to save it. Reboot the system and see if xpad is working again. If not, run `sudo apt-get purge xbox*` to remove all xboxdrv-related packages from your system. Once again, reboot and test xpad.