# Rocket League thinks controller is plugged in. There isn't one

Tags: games, steam

It wasn't doing this yesterday. Running Ubuntu 18.04, can supply other info if needed. I tried reinstalling, that didn't work. No way to turn off controller input in-game. Installed via Steam which was installed using snap.

I was just playing and I cannot stop accelerating forward.

Answer (score 0):

the default steamos-xpad-dkms controller driver that comes installed on ubuntu and its official flavours can cause problems. I recommend [following the instructions listed in the first answer of this thread to blacklist the old steamos controller driver.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working)